# How to extract rows from a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists and I'm trying to extract rows from list and plot them over a common x-variable. So I'm trying to extract each row at a time using a loop,

```
for i in range(10):
    tlist = list(zip(*v_avg_store))
    tlist[0]
    print(tlist)
    x = np.array(steps_store)
    y = np.array(tlist)
    plt.plot(x,y)

v_avg_store = [100,23,23,45,12,122], [2,1232,123,43,545,645], [234,23,43,556,33,45]
```

I want to extract each set of data and plot,

```
ex: 100,23,23,45,12,122 (y-axis) vs index (x-axis)
```

for each set on the same plot.

Which returns me the error,

> x = np.array(steps_store)
>    y = np.array(tlist)
>    plt.plot(x,y)
>    plt.xlabel("steps")
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
>            if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
>                raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension, but "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
>             if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
>                  raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have "
>
> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (99990,) and (50000, 10)

How should I address this issue? Is there a way to extract row by row form the list of list and plot them at the same time all on one plot?

Comment: Please share the entire error message, and a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC I have added a example

Comment: What is `x` here ? What is the shape of the array in `x` ?

Comment: @PrashantKumar x is a 1D array, step_store = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ..10000] and tlsit[0] = [[0, -0.6241719832649305, -0.6241719832649305, -0.6241719832649305, -0.6241719832649305, -0.624171983264930 ...]

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of `steps_store`? Also I'm assuming `tlist`is your 2 dimensional list of lists.

A 2D list example being:

`x = [[1,2,3] , [4,5,6] , [7,8,9] ,[10 , 11 ,12]] # list of lists`

The rows are considered the lists ***inside*** the list. So `x[0]` would be the row `[1 2,3]` , the column's correspond to the value inside the list of the ***row***. So `x[0][0]` is row 0, column 0 and that corresponds to 1.

You already extracted a row (assuming `tlist` is a list of lists) when you called `tlist[0]`. However you did not assign a variable to the extracted list but instead passed the entire `tlist` list it to value `y`.

Your error means that `x = np.array(steps_store)` and `y = np.array(tlist)` aren't the same dimension (one might be a 1D list, the other might be a 2D list), without knowing what exactly the values of `tlist` and `steps_store` is.

Make sure your lists dimensions agree then extract the row with:

`rowList = tlist[0]`

and pass it into a numpy array:

`x = np.array(rowList)`

Comment: thank you. x axis or step_store = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ..10000] and tlsit[0] = [[0, -0.6241719832649305, -0.6241719832649305, -0.6241719832649305, -0.6241719832649305, -0.624171983264930 ...] I tried what you told , still I'm getting the same error when I'm plotting the graph.

Comment: Can you please update your code to your latest attempt so I may have a better look at it?